# Plot 'ranges' of variable in data

Tags: r, plot, range

I have observations in the form of ranges
For eg: A 13-20, B 15-30, C 23-40, D 2-11
I want to plot them in R in form of the starting value and the end value for eg. 13 and 20 for A(upper and lower limits if you may say) in order to visualize and find out what ranges are common to certain combinations of observations. Is there a quick way to do this in R ? I think this is a very trivial problem I am having but I cant think of anyway to do it right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution using `ggplot`. It's not clear at all what format your data is in, so this assumes a data frame with columns `id` (A-D), `min`, and `max`.

```
df <- data.frame(id=LETTERS[1:4], min=c(13,15,23,2), max=c(20,30,40,11))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=id))+
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=min,ymax=max),linetype=2,color="blue")+
  geom_point(aes(y=min),size=3,color="red")+
  geom_point(aes(y=max),size=3,color="red")+
  theme_bw()
```

I've added a lot of customization just to give you an idea of how it's done. You use the `aes(...)` function to tell `ggplot` which columns in `df` map to various aesthetics of the graph. So for instance `aes(x=id)` tells `ggplot` that the values for the x-axis are to be found in the `id` column of `df`, etc.

[image]

---

**EDIT**: Response to OP's comment.

To change the size of axis text, use the `theme(...)` function, as in:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=id))+
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=min,ymax=max),linetype=2,color="blue")+
  geom_point(aes(y=min),size=3,color="red")+
  geom_point(aes(y=max),size=3,color="red")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=15))
```

[image]

Here I made the x-axis text bigger. Play around with `size=...` to get it the way you want. Also read the documentation (`?theme`) for a list of other formatting options.

Comment: Thank you so much, yes my data was in the same format in which you assumed.

Comment: Is there a way to decrease the size of the fonts on the id axis ? I have a lot of observations, so they overlap on each other. I tried using cex.axis but it showed error with the code.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear whether the dataset has range column as `string` or not i.e. `'13-20'`, `'15-30'` etc. or if it is two `numeric` columns as showed in the created example.

```
matplot(m1, xaxt='n', pch=1, ylab='range')
axis(1, at=seq_len(nrow(m1)), labels=row.names(m1))
s1 <- seq_len(nrow(m1))
arrows(s1, m1[,1], s1, m1[,2], angle=90, length=0.1)
```

[image]

If the `data` has `string` column (`d1`)

```
library(splitstackshape)
d2 <- setDF(cSplit(d1, 'range', '-'))
matplot(d2[,-1], xaxt='n', pch=1, ylab='range')
axis(1, at=seq_len(nrow(d2)), labels=d2$Col1)
arrows(s1, d2[,2], s1, d2[,3], angle=90, length=0.1)
```

#### data

```
m1 <- matrix(c(13,20, 15,30, 23,40, 2,11), 
  byrow=TRUE,dimnames=list(LETTERS[1:4],NULL), ncol=2)

d1 <- data.frame(Col1=LETTERS[1:4], 
      range=c('13-20', '15-30', '23-40', '2-11'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```