# Graphing a Difference Plot

Tags: r

I was wondering, in r, how would you plot the difference between 2 numbers so that it looks similar to the graph provided where the expected value is the 0 and the observed values are the ones deviating from 0.

Thanks

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27205999/3965651) and assuming that you have a dataframe with columns for `labels`, `min`, and `max`.

```
df <- data.frame(id=LETTERS[1:4], min=c(-2,-0.1,-3,0.3), max=c(2,4,1,2))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=id))+
    geom_linerange(aes(ymin=min,ymax=max),color="black")+
    geom_point(aes(y=min),pch=95,size=3,color="black")+
    geom_point(aes(y=max),pch=95,size=3,color="black")+
    theme_bw()
```